# Why i can't get a full path while using xpath?

Tags: html, xml, selenium-webdriver, xpath

For the following html code:

```
 <div hidden>
  <svg>
   <symbol viewBox=“0 0 8 14” id=“icon-carousel-next”>
     <path d=“M1.005 14a1 1 0 01-.71-1.71l5.296-5.288L.296></path>
   </symbol>
  <symbol viewBox=“0 0 8 14” id=“icon-carousel-prev”>
    <path d=“M1.005 14a1 1 0 01-.71-1.71l5.296-5.288L.296></path>
  <symbol id=“icon-arrow-right-bold” viewBox=“1.2 2.1 22 21”>
    <path d=“M1.005 14a1 1 0 01-.71-1.71l5.296-5.288L.296></path>
 </svg>
</div>
```

The following xpath doesn't return result:

```
//div/svg/symbol
```

I've noticed that any manipulation related to symbol element doesn't work.
Is there a known issue with this element?

Comment: It may because the `svg` element is automatically put into the SVG namespace. Try the `*[local-name()='svg'/*[local-name()='symbol']` workaround.

Answer (score 1):

to locate an `svg` the first thing that you'd have to write is:

```
//*[name()='svg']
```

the moment you write this in the browser console, it will filter out all the `SVG` nodes in the `HTMLDOM`.

Now you may not be **interested** in all the `SVG nodes` rather you are interested in a specific `svg node`. for example, let's say the first symbol in this example:

```
//*[name()='svg']//*[name()='symbol' and @id='icon-carousel-next']
```

this should get the job done.

to locate the `first path` of `first symbol`:

```
//*[name()='svg']//*[name()='symbol' and @id='icon-carousel-next']//*
```

This should give you a basic idea and should lead you in the right direction.

Comment: is *symbol* is also special? why **//*[name()='svg']//symbol** doen't work? Why *symbol* also need a special treatment?

Comment: yes exactly anything under `svg` is special, you will have to deal with these type of nodes with `//*[name()='tag_name']`

Answer (score 0):

`svg`, `path` etc. are special tag names.
Instead of

```xml
//div/svg/symbol
```

try using

```xml
//div/*[name()='svg'/*[name()='symbol']
```

or

```xml
//div/*[local-name()='svg'/*[local-name()='symbol']
```